# asp.net API cookie authentication in custom function

Tags: javascript, office-js, custom-functions-excel

How can I get data from an asp.net API that uses cookie authentication from inside a custom function.

I followed the examples from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-web-reqs.  I can make requests but fetch does not seem to be including the cookies in subsequent requests.  It seems like fetch has been nerfed in custom functions.

```
/**
 * @customfunction
 */
async function CalcbenchData(): Promise<number> {
  let batchURL = 'https://www.calcbench.com/api/NormalizedAPIBatch'
  let data = [{ "metric": "revenue", "ticker": "msft", "year": 2015, "period": 1, "datatype": 1 }]
  await login()
  return postData(batchURL, data)
}

/**
* the reponse from this function sets the ASP.net authentication token cookie
*/
async function login() {

  let email = encodeURIComponent('username')
  let password = encodeURIComponent('password')
  let url = `https://www.calcbench.com/account/LogOn?email=${email}&password=${password}`

  await fetch(url,{
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'same-origin'
  });
}


function postData(url = '', data = {}): Promise<number> {
  return fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'same-origin', // no-cors, cors, *same-origin

    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },

    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrer: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *client
    body: JSON.stringify(data), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  }).then(response => {
    return response.json()
  }).then(json => {
    return json.value
  }) // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects 
}
```

7/25/2019 17:49:54  Verbose Runtime [Console] [Log] Unexpected CustomFunctions [Execution] [End] [Failure] [RejectedPromise] Function=CALCBENCHDATA TypeError: Network request failed {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is currently not possible with the custom functions runtime on windows (as it is a seperate process from the authentication dialog) but is under active development on how we enable this. Please watch this item on GitHub for upcoming updates: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Custom-Functions/issues/118. We'll likely update it in a couple of weeks time.

Thanks

Comment: Does the custom-functions fetch implementation support cookies on the web/Mac?  A variant of the above example did not work on the Excel in the browser.

Comment: Hey there, not yet. Currently even though on web and mac, we run the custom functions inside of a web view, this is different from the web view which you authenticate in. The update will introduce a "Shared App" model which will force the functions and commands to run in the same web view instance as the taskpane (so then the cookie will be shared).